# Интеграция AppoDeal

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь интегрировать AppoDeal  в свое приложение, все сделал, но если вставить этот код во фрагменте то выскакивает ошибка на слове "this"

```
String appKey = "2816167553ee1b3ffb303beb7841d4976a8cebf41a72b111";
Appodeal.initialize(this, appKey);
```

Comment: Какая ошибка и чему равен (какой объект) `this`?

Comment: in AppoDeal cannot be applied

Comment: контекст в фрагменте передается методом `getActivity()`, а не `this`

Comment: Спасибо, ныне буду знать)

Comment: Плохо, что документация не точечная, я бы и не задал глупый вопрос, если бы знал, что вводить в поиске документаций. Не задам же я в поиске среди документации это - "А что нужно делать, когда во фрагменте this светится ошибкой?", навряд ли мне поиск дал бы нужный результат.

Comment: Вам надо было просто навести мышью на название метода и он бы вам сказал, что хочет увидеть в виде аргументов. Так бы вы поняли, что вам нужен контекст и стали бы его искать.